Batch and custom metadata
if we are running the batch using the custom metadata and if we are changing the custom metadata while the batch is in execution is there any impact on batch.
XyzBatch obj = new XyzBatch();
database.extecuteBatch(obj,1);


It depends on how you write the code. There are three general moments you can set the custom metadata.
public class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
  CustomMetadata__mdt[] settings;
  public BatchClass() { 
  // Option 1: This would fix the settings before the start method
    settings = CustomMetadata__mdt.getAll();
  }
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    // Option 2: This would fix the settings as the start method is executed
    settings = CustomMetadata__mdt.getAll();
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
       SELECT Id FROM Account
    ]);
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
    // Option 3: This would set the settings for this transaction only
    settings = CustomMetadata__mdt.getAll();
  }

Consider this example:
Database.scheduleBatch(new BatchClass(), 'JobName', 15);

With option 1, even if you change the Custom Metadata within the next 15 minutes, the batch class would use the original metadata. Option 2 would allow you to change the Custom Metadata up until the start method is called 15 minutes later. With option 3, you can change the Custom Metadata at any time, and the very next execute method will see the changes.
